# Content Type Issue with AFAmazonS3Manager (iOS)

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, content-type

I have an issue retrieving images with AFAmazonS3Manager. I can upload to Amazon S3 just fine but I noticed when I try to use the image URL in a browser it doesn't open as a web URL. It asks to save the image. I think this is why images are not working in my app. The Content-Type uses "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and I need the Content-Type to be "image/jpeg".

Does anyone know if there is a setting for Amazon S3 to open images in web URLs? And how do I change the Content-Type for my image URLs?

I'm using AFAmazonS3Manager (cocoapod) for iOS. My pods are updated and I am using a current version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I modified the AFURLRequestSerialization.m file to default to my desired content-type which is jpeg. I added a line of code in this if statement:

```
if (![mutableRequest valueForHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"]) {
[mutalbleRequest setValue:@"image/jpeg" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
}
```

Now all my image URLs open in the browser. I checked the meta data setting in AmazonS3 and it serves up jpegs. Hope this saves someone some time.